# Gradient Overlay with Background Image

Tags: html, css

I have a section that needs a background image with a gradient overlay over the whole section and I can't achieve that,
this is My CSS Code:

```
.first-section{
    background-image:  linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(43,59,144), rgb(255,255,255)), url("section1Background.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

and this is my page html

```
<section class="first-section">
</section>
```

it either works with the image if I removed the gradient section or the only the gradient section works without the image

Comment: your gradient is a solid coloration, you need to use transparent color

Comment: Have you tried simply just adding :`background-blend-mode: multiply;` it works for me

Comment: @Sophie that worked for me as I needed thanks